# Remove a child from the stage createjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs

I was wondering if you are able to remove an specific child from the stage. I know that you can do this:

```
stage.removeAllChildren();
stage.update();
```

But with this you will clear all the canvas... is there a way to do something like this

```
stage.removeAllChildren(name_of_the_child);
stage.update();
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is this `removeChild(child)` method , take a look at the documentation 
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html#method_removeChild